# How to get different values from another component every time when it is added?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that contain 3 text box 2 of them are input and third one get the value from the map component. when i select the map address it shows in next map address text box also,  for clear view my text box is like :
[1 branch][1]

when I click add branch the three text is added again but the map value is presetted like this:
[after add branch][2]

My code is :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/test.css';
import Header from './Header';
import SimpleModal from './modal';
import Branch from './branch';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const TOUR_STEPS = [
    {
      target: ".step1",
      content:  "View the cart you’ve added here",
      disableBeacon: true,
    },
    {
      target: ".step2",
      content:
        "View the cart you’ve added here",
    },
    {
      target: ".step3",
      content: "Contact the developer",
    },
    {
      target: ".step4",
      content: "We accept returns after 14 days max",
    },
  ];
class Communication extends React.Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
          input: {},
          errors: {},
          counter:0,  
          values: [
            { address1: { value: ''}, address2: { value: ''} }
          ]
        };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.appendDiv = this.appendDiv.bind(this);
        this.mapFunctionHere = this.mapFunctionHere.bind(this);
      }
         
      handleChange(event) {
        let input = this.state.input;
        input[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
      
        this.setState({
          input
        });
      }
      handleChangeInput = (counter, key, value) => {
        const newValues = [...this.state.values]
        newValues[counter][key].value = value
        this.setState({ values: newValues })
      }
    
      mapFunctionHere(param) {
        this.setState({
          MapAddr:param[0],
        });
      } 
      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        if(!this.validate()){
            console.log(this.state.values);  
            let input = {};
            input["phoneNumber"] = "";
            input["password"] = "";
            this.setState({input:input});  
            console.log(this.state.MapAddr);
            console.log(this.state.input);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("mobile", this.state.input.phoneNumber);
            formData.append("password",this.state.input.password);
            formData.append("fcm_token", 1);
            formData.append("device_id", 1);
            formData.append("source", 1);
            formData.append("device_name", 1);
            formData.append("os_version", 1);
            axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: 'url',
              data: formData,
              config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data','Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS', }}
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                  //handle success
                  console.log(response);
                  if(response.data.result === true){
                    window.location.href = "/Detail";
                  }
                  else{
                    alert(response.data.msg);
                  }
                  console.log(response.data.msg);
                  console.log(response.data.result);
              })
              .catch(function (response) {
                 
                  console.log(response);
                
                
                  
              });
            }
          };
            
          renderBranches = () => {
            const { counter } = this.state
            const result = []
            for (let i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
              result.push(this.renderBranch(i))
            }
            return result
          }
          appendDiv = () => {
            this.setState({
              counter: this.state.counter + 1,
              values: [
                ...this.state.values,
                { address1: { value: ''}, address2: { value: '' } }
              ]
            })
          }
          
      
      validate(){
          let input = this.state.input;
          let errors = {};
          let isValid = true;
       
          if (!input["fullname"]) {
            isValid = false;
            errors["fullname"] = "Please enter your fullname.";
          }
      
          if (typeof input["fullname"] !== "undefined") {
            const re = /^\S*$/;
            if(input["fullname"].length < 1 || !re.test(input["fullname"])){
                isValid = false;
                errors["fullname"] = "Please enter  fullname.";
            }
          }
      
          if (!input["address1"]) {
            isValid = false;
            errors["address1"] = "Please enter your address.";
          }

      
          if (typeof input["address1"] !== "undefined") {
            if(input["address1"].length < 4){
                isValid = false;
                errors["address1"] = "Please add at least 4 address.";
            }
          }

          if (!input["address2"]) {
            isValid = false;
            errors["address2"] = "Please enter your address.";
          }

      
          if (typeof input["address2"] !== "undefined") {
            if(input["address2"].length < 4){
                isValid = false;
                errors["address2"] = "Please add at least 4 address.";
            }
          }
          if (!input["address3"]) {
            isValid = false;
            errors["address3"] = "Please enter your address.";
          }

      
          if (typeof input["address3"] !== "undefined") {
            if(input["address3"].length < 4){
                isValid = false;
                errors["address3"] = "Please add at least 4 address.";
            }
          }

          if (!input["branch"]) {
            isValid = false;
            errors["branch"] = "Please Enter No of branch.";
          }

      
          if (typeof input["branch"] !== "undefined") {
            if(input["branch"].length < 6){
                isValid = false;
                errors["branch"] = "Please  Enter No of branch.";
            }
          }

         
      
          this.setState({
            errors: errors
          });
      
          return isValid;
      }    
      
      renderBranch = counter => {
        const { values,MapAddr } = this.state
        
        return (
          <>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Store Address</label>
              <input type="text"
                value={values[counter].address1.value}
                onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address1', event.target.value)}  
                className="form-control code"
                name="address1"
                placeholder="Pincode"
              />   
              <span className="form-text" id="errtext">
                {values[counter].address1.error}    
              </span>                                             
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                  <input type="text" className="form-control code"
                    value={values[counter].address2.value}
                    onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address2', event.target.value)}
                    name="address2"
                    placeholder="address" />
                  <span className="form-text" id="errtext">
                    {values[counter].address2.error}    
                  </span>
                </div>              
              <div className="col-md-auto">
                <p style={{margin:"5px"}}>and</p>
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                  <SimpleModal className="form-control" mapFunctionHere={this.mapFunctionHere}/>
                </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">                                               
              <input type="text"
                className="form-control code"
                value={MapAddr}
                onChange={event => this.handleChangeInput(counter, 'address3', MapAddr)}
                name="address3"
                placeholder="address"
                readOnly
              />     
              <span className="form-text" id="errtext">
                 
              </span>           
            </div>
          </>
        )
      }

    render() {
        var rows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            rows.push(<Branch key={i} />);
        }
       
        return <>
        <Header data={TOUR_STEPS}/>
        <div id="kt_body" className="header-fixed header-mobile-fixed subheader-enabled subheader-fixed aside-enabled aside-fixed aside-minimize-hoverable page-loading">
    <div className="d-flex flex-column-fluid">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="card card-custom">
            <div className="card-body p-0">
                
                <div className="wizard wizard-3" id="kt_wizard_v3" data-wizard-state="step-first" data-wizard-clickable="true">
                    
                    <div className="wizard-nav">
                        <div className="wizard-steps px-8 py-8 px-lg-15 py-lg-3">
                            
                            <div className="wizard-step full" data-wizard-type="step">
                                <div className="wizard-label">
                                    <h3 className="wizard-title">
                                    <span>1.</span>Verify Your Details</h3>
                                    <div className="wizard-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            <div className="wizard-step full" data-wizard-type="step">
                                <div className="wizard-label">
                                    <h3 className="wizard-title">
                                    <span>2.</span>classification</h3>
                                    <div className="wizard-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           
                            <div className="wizard-step full" data-wizard-type="step" >
                                <div className="wizard-label">
                                    <h3 className="wizard-title">
                                    <span>3.</span>Authentication</h3>
                                    <div className="wizard-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="wizard-step full" data-wizard-type="step" data-wizard-state="current">
                                <div className="wizard-label">
                                    <h3 className="wizard-title">
                                    <span>4.</span>Communication</h3>
                                    <div className="wizard-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="wizard-step full" data-wizard-type="step">
                                <div className="wizard-label">
                                    <h3 className="wizard-title">
                                    <span>5.</span>Documentaion</h3>
                                    <div className="wizard-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="wizard-step mob" data-wizard-type="step" data-wizard-state="current">
                                <div className="wizard-label">
                                    <h3 className="wizard-title">
                                    <span>(4/5)</span>Communication</h3>
                                    <div className="wizard-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div className="row justify-content-center py-10 px-8 py-lg-12 px-lg-10">
                        <div className="col-xl-12 col-xxl-7">
                            
                            <form className="form" id="kt_form">
                                
                                <div className="pb-5" data-wizard-type="step-content" data-wizard-state="current">
                                    <h4 className="mb-10 font-weight-bold text-dark">Business Communication Details</h4>
                                    
                                   
                                    
                                    <div className="row ">
                                        <div className="col-xl-6">
                                           
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label>Store/Brand Name</label>
                                                <input type="text"
                                                 value={this.state.input.fullname}
                                                 onChange={this.handleChange} 
                                                  className="form-control code" 
                                                  name="fullname" placeholder="Brand Name" />
                                              <span className="form-text" id="errtext">{this.state.errors.fullname}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Does it has Branches ?</label>
                                            <div className="checkbox-inline">
                                                <label className="checkbox">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes3"/>
                                                    <span></span>
                                                    Yes
                                                </label>
                                                
                                                <label >
                                                       <input type="text"
                                                        className="form-control code" 
                                                        name="branch"  value={this.state.input.branch}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                                                        placeholder="Pincode"  />
                                                  
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <span className="form-text" id="errtext">{this.state.errors.branch}</span>
                                        </div>                                         
                                        {this.renderBranches()} 
                                                  
                                                    <div className="toolti">
                                                      <input type="button" className="addbranch"  onClick={this.appendDiv} value="Add Branch" />
                                                    <span className="tooltitext">You can add branches even after registration 
                                                      from your dashboard</span>
                                                  </div>
                                                
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between border-top mt-5 pt-10">
                                    <div className="mr-2">
                                        {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bolder text-uppercase px-9 py-4">Previous</button> */}
                                        <Link to="/authentication" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bolder text-uppercase px-9 py-4" data-wizard-type="action-next"  style={{backgroundColor:"#3951A0",borderColor:"#3951A0"}}>Previous</Link>

                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                    {/* <Link to="/documentation" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bolder text-uppercase px-9 py-4" data-wizard-type="action-next"  style={{backgroundColor:"#3951A0",borderColor:"#3951A0"}}>Next</Link> */}

                                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary font-weight-bolder text-uppercase px-9 py-4"
                                          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                                        style={{backgroundColor:"#3951A0",borderColor:"#3951A0"}}>Next</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </form>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
</>
 }
}

export default Communication;
```

In select on map i am calling a modal my modal code is:

```
class SimpleModal extends React.Component {
//export default function SimpleModal() {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Set initial state
    this.state = {
      setOpen: false,
      name: ""
    }
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.someFunctionHere = this.someFunctionHere.bind(this);
  }
  // const classes = useStyles();
  // // getModalStyle is not a pure function, we roll the style only on the first render
  // const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  // //const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  someFunctionHere(param) {
    this.props.mapFunctionHere(param);  
}
   handleOpen() {
    this.setState({
      setOpen: true
    });
  };

  handleClose(){
    this.setState({
      setOpen: false
    });
  };
  
  render()
  {
  return <>
    <div style={{position:"absolute"}}>
      <button type="button" className="form-control map" onClick={this.handleOpen}>
        Select on Map
      </button>
      <Modal
        open={this.state.setOpen}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        <div  className="paper" >
      <Map someFunctionHere={this.someFunctionHere} />
      {/* <SimpleModal /> */}
      <button type="button" style={{height: "43px",width: "138px",
      borderRadius: "4px",backgroundColor: "#3951A0",color:'white',border:"none",float:"right"}} onClick={this.handleClose}>
        Close
      </button>
    </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  </>
  }
}

export default SimpleModal;
```

In modal i am calling my map :

```
class Map extends React.Component {
//const Map = () => {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Set initial state
    this.state = {
      addres: '',
      defaultLocation: DefaultLocation,
      location:DefaultLocation,
      zoom:DefaultZoom
    }
    this.handleChangeLocation = this.handleChangeLocation.bind(this);
  }
 
 handleChangeLocation (lat, lng){
  this.setState({
    location: {lat:lat, lng:lng},
    })
    console.log(lat,lng)
    axios.get(`url`)
      .then(res => {
       console.log(res.data.results[0].formatted_address);
      // const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
       const setaaddres = [res.data.results[0].formatted_address,lat,lng];
       this.setState({addres: res.data.results[0].formatted_address});
       this.props.someFunctionHere(setaaddres); 
      })
  }
  
   handleChangeZoom (newZoom){
   this.setState({
    zoom: newZoom,
    })
  }
  

render() {

  return (
    <>
    <div>
  
 <input type='text' style={{width:"100%"}} defaultValue={this.state.addres} />
 
  
  <MapPicker defaultLocation={this.state.defaultLocation}
    zoom={this.state.zoom}
    style={{height:'500px'}}
    onChangeLocation={this.handleChangeLocation} 
    onChangeZoom={this.handleChangeZoom}
    apiKey='AIzaSyB-tpDLb6LG767qc9ttvDrf23IOqLxheXk'/>
    </div>
  </>
  );
}
}
;

export default Map;
```

How to get different map values for different text box ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6LX9.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpT01.png